# How to distribute an app on Mac?

Tags: java, xml, windows, macos, netbeans

What is the current best way to distribute an application on a Mac?

What I would like is a build.xml that, when built (in NetBeans) will output an .exe (windows) and .app (mac) into the dist folder.

I currently have a build.xml that compacts the program into a .zip file for distribution, but would like to add an .app and .exe for mac and windows.

Here is my current build.xml that outputs to a zip file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="name" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description></description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

    <property file="version.properties"/>
    <property name="version" value="${version.major}.${version.minor}.${version.patch}" />
    <property name="executable.name" value="company-${version.product.name}-${version}" />

    <target name="-post-jar" description="Generates a versioned name for the JAR file">
        <mkdir dir="LOGS" />
        <move file="dist/${ant.project.name}.jar" tofile="dist/${executable.name}.jar" />
        <antcall target="generate-run-scripts" />
        <antcall target="deliverable-osx" />
        <antcall target="deliverable-windows" />
    </target>

    <target name="generate-run-scripts" description="Generate batch files to run the application">
        <echo file="dist/run.bat">
            java -cp ${executable.name}.jar -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Xmx2048m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote classname
        </echo>
        <echo file="dist/run.sh">#!/bin/sh
            java -cp ${executable.name}.jar -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Xmx2048m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote classname
        </echo>
    </target>

    <target name="deliverable-windows" description="Deployment files for Windows runtime">
        <property name="zip.name" value="Project-${version}-windows" />
        <zip destfile="dist/${zip.name}.zip">
            <zipfileset file="dist/${executable.name}.jar" />
            <zipfileset file="logging.properties"/>
            <zipfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar" prefix="lib" />
            <zipfileset file="dist/run.bat"/>
            <zipfileset dir="LOGS" excludes="*" />
            <zipfileset dir="files" excludes="*" />
            <zipfileset file="changelog.txt"/>
        </zip>
    </target>

    <target name="deliverable-osx" description="Deployment files for Apple OS-X runtime">
        <property name="zip.name" value="Project-${version}-OSX" />
        <zip destfile="dist/${zip.name}.zip">
            <zipfileset file="dist/${executable.name}.jar" />
            <zipfileset file="logging.properties"/>
            <zipfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar" prefix="lib" />
            <zipfileset file="dist/run.sh" filemode="755" />
            <zipfileset dir="LOGS" excludes="*" />
            <zipfileset dir="files" excludes="*" />
            <zipfileset file="changelog.txt"/>
        </zip>
    </target>    
</project>
```

Here is my attempt at outputting an .app file. It outputs a .app file, but displays an error message every time I try running it. (Although after running it again its not even outputting an .app file).

I used [Packaging a Java App](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) to create the build.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="name" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description></description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

    <property file="version.properties"/>
    <property name="version" value="${version.major}.${version.minor}.${version.patch}" />
    <property name="executable.name" value="company-${version.product.name}-${version}" />
    <property environment="env" />

    <taskdef name="bundleapp"
             classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
             classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />

    <target name="ai_debug">
        <bundleapp outputdirectory="dist"
            name="Project"
            displayname="Project-${version}"
            identifier="classname"
            mainclassname="classname">
            <runtime dir="${java.home}" />
            <classpath file="dist/Project.jar"/>
        </bundleapp>
    </target>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: I would verify that the Java runtime is been included in the .app package (it's just a directory)

Comment: Also I'm getting "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/Info.plist" When running the build.xml file.